# How can I use layers of existing docker image when build another one?

Tags: docker

I have built one docker image via Dockerfile. And then I've found a mistake in the last layer. So when I rebuild the image I see that the layers are made anew. Can I use existing layers of the existing image? It takes too much time to make them.

**UPD**

Thanks for the answering, I have rebuild the image without time-wasting layers (Qt debian packages comes enough, without building Qt from sources). For the moment I cannot make sure that layers are reused so I believe they are so.

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile ? It should properly cache everything by default if it hasn't change

Comment: I use directives from Dockerfile from here: https://github.com/erstrom/docker-qt based on another image (jenkins slave image is specified in FROM). Also, I use Docker for Windows - may be this does matter...

Comment: Looks fine indeed, can you provide the logs of thee building phase ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I had to reset that Docker Desktop (for windows 10) to its defaults because it permanently failed to restart with custom insecure registries, so I have lost all images was built. Also, I have found that qt5 image working with only installed qtbase5-dev + qt5-default, so the long-time-layer with build qt from source became unnecessary. Thank you for reaction, it seems that there is no need to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The build process will reuse the existing layers, Depending on how you are positioning your Dockerfile directives. There are some [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) to use.

Back to the caching the cached layers will show up as "Using Cache" in you build output.

For even more enhancements your can use the new BUILDKIT to do to the builds.
to enable build kit do:
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .`

More over [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements).

Comment: Thank you for answer, I've tried DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 and find it nice. But my build does not reuse existings layers. Well, I am building an image by this Dockerfile: https://github.com/erstrom/docker-qt but based on jenkins-slave image (I'm using another FROM). I'm using docker for windows. May windows implementation of docker bring such an issue?

Comment: The Dockerfile looks good to me, can you tell me more about the jenkins slave?

Comment: It is eeacms/jenkins-slave. `FROM eeacms/jenkins-slave` - after this instructions of  mentioned Dockerfile follows (except its FROM).